# ReFS (NTFS successor) filesystem support

Tags: windows, filesystem, ntfs

Wikipedia says of ReFS:

> Resilient File System (ReFS), codenamed "Protogon", is a Microsoft proprietary file system introduced with Windows Server 2012 with the intent of becoming the "next generation" file system after NTFS.

Does MacOS support mounting and read/write access to ReFS?

If so, what are the limitations?

Comment: MS don't even support ReFS volume creation on Win 10 any more. Paragon integrated it with their Windows file system tools, but never for Mac. Since MS dropped it from Win10 2 years ago, I don't see any future for it on Mac. Essentially, as it was designed as a "server only" file system, no-one is really expected to be accessing it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would plan on zero support since Microsoft only supports their server os and many desirable features are still
absent for this filesystem like quotas, bootable filesystem, removable media, encryption, etc...

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview

It looks like Microsoft is adding a scrubbable and more resilient / thin provisioning layer similar to Apple’s successful transition APFS that completed on iOS several years ago and is basically complete on macOS now.

I would expose any ReFS data over a stable API like SMB or iSCSI rather than expect to read or interact directly with that flavor of storage from macOS.

All is not lost if Apple doesn't ship filesystem support as there are several user space filesystem extensions that have a long heritage of adding useful filesystems:

- https://osxfuse.github.io
- https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2

I don't see one for ReFS but I'm sure someone can write or show one once that happens and edit this portion of the answer to update it.